# Hibernate Criteria: Projection with TransferObject

Tags: hibernate, hql, criteria, jpql

How could I Convert the HQL code below to a Hibernate Criteria query?

```
SELECT
    new com.project.to.PersonTO(
        person.firstName,
        person.lastName
    )
FROM
    Person person
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Below :-

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Person.class);
criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.property("firstName"), "firstName") .add(Projections.property("lastName"), "lastName"))
                    .setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(PersonTO.class));
```